# How can I installing an R package with 64-bits types without changing the Makevars file?

Tags: r, compilation, 64-bit, large-data

I installed the `largeVis` package on my windows PC. The usual installation installs a 32-bit version. When I load the package I get the message:

```
Loading required package: Matrix
largeVis was compiled with 32-bit types. This will limit the size of the datasets it can process. Consider recompiling with -DARMA_64BIT_WORD
```

Appearantly I would have to change the file `Makevars.win` and add this line.
As I don't have admin rights, I can not do this.

Is there are way to install the package using 64 bits the form of a command or similar where I can pass the argument `-DARMA_64BIT_WORD` ?

My session info is

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] largeVis_0.1.9.1 Matrix_1.2-6    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.3.1      gtable_0.2.0     Rcpp_0.12.7      ggplot2_2.1.0   
 [8] grid_3.3.1       munsell_0.4.3    lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: You should not need to edit the package's `Makevars.win` [according to the author](https://github.com/elbamos/largeVis#building-notes). Try running [this code](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/2d6c35837c277f85d0aeb55a7b9bba54).

Comment: @nrussell thanks for the comment and the code! I tried to install the CRAN version. Some security setting here makes a call to devtools::install_github fail. Can I use your approach with the CRAN version too?

Comment: You should be able to replace the `devtools::` call with `install.packages("largeVis", type = "source")`.

Comment: In this case I get an error of status 127 from the make command : make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" -f "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/.R/Makevars" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' SHLIB="largeVis.dll"  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'largeVis'OBJECTS="RcppExports.o denseneighbors.o distance.o edgeweights.o gradients.o hdbscan.o largeVis.o sparse.o test-runner.o testcfunctions.o"' had status 127

Comment: Do you have the latest Rtools installed on your machine?

Comment: I have Rtools version 3.2.0.1948 ... this is maybe my problem ... but it is not easy to "beg our IT" to upgrade tools ... could this be the problem? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You will need to have your admin install the latest version (Rtool34) from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) because that package requires a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Great. I will do that! Then it should work out with all the hints and code you have given me. Thank you!

Comment: error:                                Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" -f "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/.R/Makevars" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' SHLIB="largeVis.dll" OBJECTS="RcppExports.o denseneighbors.o distance.o edgeweights.o gradients.o hdbscan.o largeVis.o sparse.o test-runner.o testcfunctions.o"' had status 2